# How do I find/list a file or directory with specific name inside a directory and its subdirectories in Java?

Tags: java, io

What my file/directory tree on Linux (Redhat) looks like.

```
/search
├───sub1
│   └───data (directory)
└───sub2
    └───data (file)
```

What I already tried is listed below.

Example I (I assumed directories are files in Linux and Java knows this)

```
FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/search"),
                        new NameFileFilter("data"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Exampe II

```
FileUtils.listFilesAndDirectories(new File("/search"),
                        new NameFileFilter("data"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The above code examples does not print "/search/sub1/data" and /search/sub2/data" like I want them to. `FileUtils` is from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You write the code to do the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using Java 7 `Files.walkFileTree`, `PathMatcher` and `FileVisitor` like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class MyVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:data");

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (matcher.matches(dir.getFileName())) {
            System.out.println("dir found " + dir);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (matcher.matches(file.getFileName())) {
            System.out.println("file found " + file);
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("full/path/to/your/search"), new MyVisitor());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an option with Apache Commons FileUtils to do that? I would find that a lot more efficient (fewer lines of code).

Comment: @TonyStark i tried various methods from FileUtils but couldn't achieve what you wanted using FileUtils, that's why i wrote the code in Java 7 .